# Group list by belongs_to relation including all the belongs_to object properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by, nested

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :room
 end


class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :users
      validates :name, presence: true
      validates :location, presence: true
end
```

I have a filtered list of users and I'm grouping the list by room like this:

```
users.group_by(&:room_id)
```

This gives me the following hash:

```
{
 1=>[array of users belonging to room with id 1],
 2=>[array of users belonging to room with id 2]
}
```

I would like to have an array of Rooms including their users like this:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  name: room1,
  location: location1,
  users: [array of users belonging to room with id 1],
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: room2,
  location: location2,
  users: [array of users belonging to room with id 2]
 }
]
```

Comment: Try `Room.joins(:users).select("rooms.name, rooms.location").group('rooms.id')`

Comment: This gives me all users for every Room. The list of users I want to sort by Room is filtered based on properties of user(name, age, gender). Bassically I want only the filtered list of users by Room.